# Maybe I misunderstood the update method of Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

Using a Web API, I want to update one record and two m-to-n relation tables in the PUT method. For this I found the update method of Entity Framework. However, my code further down does nothing at all. Is it possible that I have fundamentally misunderstood something there?

```cs
[HttpPut("Roles/{roleID}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateRole(int roleID, Role updatedRole) {
    // Validate data
    if (roleID != updatedRole.ID)
        return BadRequest("ID missmatch.");

    if (!updatedRole.Validate(out string problems))
        return BadRequest(problems);

    // Apply modified relations
    updatedRole.ApplyModifiedRelations();

    // Setup db connection
    MpaContext db = _mpaContext;

    Response.RegisterForDispose(db);

    // Save changes
    db.Update(updatedRole);

    // I've added these two afterwords, but it also doesn't update anything
    if (updatedRole.HasModifiedClientIDs)
        db.UpdateRange(updatedRole.ClientRoles);

    if(updatedRole.HasModifiedViewerIDs)
        db.UpdateRange(updatedRole.RoleViewers);

    try {
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return Problem(ex.Message);

    }

    return Ok();
}

public void ApplyModifiedRelations() {
    if (HasModifiedClientIDs) { 
        ClientRoles = new List<ClientRole>(
            _ClientIDs.Select(c => new ClientRole() { ClientID = c, RoleID = ID })
        );
    }

    if (HasModifiedViewerIDs) {
        RoleViewers = new List<RoleViewer>(
            _ViewerIDs.Select(v => new RoleViewer() { RoleID = ID, ViewerID = v })
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your object didn't exist in db context (because you get it from request). So EF can't update it.
Try this

```
db.Entry(updatedRole).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you for your idea. But that is basically what the `DbContext.Update()` method does.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. You have to actually load the relationship before updating it. I modified my ApplyModifiedRelations method accordingly:

```cs
public async Task ApplyModifiedRelations(MpaContext db) {
    if (HasModifiedClientIDs) {
        await db.Entry(this).Collection(r => r.ClientRoles).LoadAsync();

        ClientRoles = new List<ClientRole>(
            _ClientIDs.Select(c => new ClientRole() { ClientID = c, RoleID = ID })
        );
    }

    if (HasModifiedViewerIDs) {
        await db.Entry(this).Collection(r => r.RoleViewers).LoadAsync();

        RoleViewers = new List<RoleViewer>(
            _ViewerIDs.Select(v => new RoleViewer() { RoleID = ID, ViewerID = v })
        );
    }
}
```

I also moved that method call below the `db.Update` call. But I don't know, if this makes any difference.